# Access index in v-for when iterating over object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am trying to access the index of an iteration in [Vue](http://vuejs.org/)'s `v-for` binding.

This is the object:

```
const obj = {  
  obj1: {  
    some: 'data'
  },
  obj2: {  
    some: 'data'
  },
  obj3: {  
    some: 'data'
  }
}
```

and I'm looping over it:

```
<li v-for="(object, index) in obj" :key="index">{{ object.some }}</li>
```

The problem is that contrary to looping over an `array` the `index` variable in case of looping over an `object` like this does not hold the iteration index (e.g. `0`, `1`, `2`) but actually holds the object name `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`.

Why is it behaving like that and how can I get my precious iteration index back in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) when iterating over an object the second parameter is the object key. To access the index you should add a third parameter as in the following example:

```
<div v-for="(value, name, index) in object">
  {{ index }}. {{ name }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Comment: who can read is clearly in a better position. Thanks *facepalm*