# How to transcribe Vue associative array into HTML form input values

Tags: html, json, vue.js

I have an HTML form, which used to have input values based on a Vue array like so:

```
// Vue Var
var postIDarr = [postID, postID, etc., etc.];
// HTML
<input v-for="(id, index) in postIDarr" type="hidden" name="postIDArr[]" :key="index" :value="id">
```

This worked fine for a while, but now I want to make the array an associative array, encoding both the postID and the userID for processing on the backend. The array in Vue has the structure as follows;

```
var postIDarr = {
    userID: postID,
};
// These are placeholders obviously
```

How would I be able to encode both of these values into the HTML form?

Wasn't entirely sure how to write this question without being repetitive, if you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: The documentation for v-for over objects is here:

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access index in v-for when iterating over object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589420/access-index-in-v-for-when-iterating-over-object)

Answer (score 1):

if you have an object like :

```
var postIDarr = {
    userID: postID,
}
```

and you want want render it using v-for by showing the key and value, so you could do it like :

```
 v-for="(id,key, index) in postIDarr"
```

`id` refers to `postID`

`key` refers to `userID`

Comment: and how would I attach both of these values into an array input?

Comment: what do you mean by attach?